# Reset Nested Form in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-forms

This SHOULD be simple, but I'm finding it to be quite daunting.

I have an Angular2 (RC.5) form with a nested form component.  I'm not 100% sure I'm doing THAT right, but it's working for now...

(NOTE: the names were changed and sample was simplified to protect the client)

Nested Form Control:

```
@Component({
  selector: "nested-form",
  templateUrl: "Content/templates/shared/nestedForm.htm"
})
export class NestedFormComponent extends FormGroup implements OnInit {
  // Implementation omitted
}
```

Main Form:

```
@Component({
  selector: "main-form",
  templateUrl: "Content/templates/core/mainForm.htm",
  directives: [NestedFormComponent]
})
export class MainFormComponent implements OnInit {

  public formObj: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private fb:FormBuilder
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Create our form group
    this.formObj= this.fb.group({
        myNested: this.fb.array([new NestedFormComponent()])
    });        
  }

  // Rest of implementation omitted
}
```

So this works for everything EXCEPT resetting the form (one of the client requirements).  I've tried calling reset on the parent form and I've tried calling reset on the nested form by doing the following:

```
  private resetNestedForm() {
    let nested = <NestedFormComponent>(
      <FormArray>this.formObj.controls["myNested"])
      .controls[0];
    nested.reset();
  }
```

I've tried implementing my own "reset" method on the nested control and manually resetting the controls, but when I get to the method on the nested form object that gets returned from the parent controls array, none of the controls on the nested form object are instantiated - which I know isn't the case because I get data back from the nested form's emitter that I implemented (not shown).

So has anyone had any success in getting **NESTED** form controls to reset to their original state?  How can I do this?

Comment: I was able to get this to somewhat work, but I had to rip a lot of this apart.  I ended up refactoring my child form to make the form group a property of the component rather than trying to extend the FormGroup.